# Adding GTK3 (C++) gtk_gl_area widget to container/box halts *all* UI elements?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, gtk, gtk3

I've run into a strange bug in GTK 3.16/3.18 (tried both) where packing/adding a gtk_gl_area widget to a gtk_box or gtk_event_box container causes all of the UI elements to freeze, even when gtk_main_do_iteration() is called. They receive no *visual* updates (e.g., the buttons/menus/radio buttons do not highlight/change when the cursor clicks or hovers over them) *but*, they still seem to respond to mouse *input*, despite not visually doing so.

Has anyone experienced this? Is there a solution? Am I not meant to pack the GL area into a container? I can find very little documentation on the gl_area widget (re)implemented in GTK 3.16, and even fewer examples.

I should note that it freezes *regardless* of whether or not the m_GLDisplay.initGLDisplay() function is called (or if that class is used at all). Merely *packing* the gl_area is what causes the other UI elements to freeze. If I comment out the gtk_gox_pack_end() call where it is packed, everything works again. Even with the m_GLDisplay.initGLDisplay() function called.

GTK window source code (relevant snippet):

```
topRightContainer  = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL,0);
videoPaneHeaderBar = gtk_header_bar_new();
videoPane          = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL,0);
videoGLArea        = gtk_gl_area_new();

gtk_header_bar_set_title(GTK_HEADER_BAR(videoPaneHeaderBar),"Video Feed");
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(topRightContainer), videoPaneHeaderBar, false, false, 0);
gtk_box_pack_end(GTK_BOX(topRightContainer), videoGLArea, false, false, 0);
gtk_widget_set_size_request(GTK_WIDGET(videoGLArea), 200,100);

m_GLDisplay.initGLDisplay(videoGLArea);
```

GLDisplay class:

```
#include "GUI/GLDisplay.h"

GLDisplay::GLDisplay() {
    return;
}

GLDisplay::~GLDisplay() {
    return;
}

static gboolean
render (GtkGLArea *area, GdkGLContext *context, gpointer callback_data)
{

    GLDisplay *glDisplay = static_cast<GLDisplay*>(callback_data);
    // we can start by clearing the buffer

    gdk_gl_context_make_current(context);
    glClearColor (0.5, 0.1, 0, 0);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // draw your object
    //draw_an_object ();

    // we completed our drawing; the draw commands will be
    // flushed at the end of the signal emission chain, and
    // the buffers will be drawn on the window
    return TRUE;
}

/// initGLDisplay()
/// This passes in the required variables and references needed by the display class

void GLDisplay::initGLDisplay(GtkWidget *glArea) {
    m_glArea = glArea;
    //gtk_gl_area_attach_buffers(GTK_GL_AREA(m_glArea));
   // gtk_gl_area_set_has_alpha(GTK_GL_AREA(m_glArea), true);
    gtk_gl_area_set_auto_render(GTK_GL_AREA(m_glArea), true);

    // connect to the "render" signal
    g_signal_connect (m_glArea, "render", G_CALLBACK (render), this);

    drawLoopThread = std::thread(&GLDisplay::drawLoop, this);
    drawLoopThread.detach();

    std::cout << "GL Initialized" << std::endl;

}

/// drawLoop()
/// This is the loop meant to govern refresh rate

void GLDisplay::drawLoop() {
    while (!terminate){
        gtk_gl_area_queue_render(GTK_GL_AREA(m_glArea));
        ros::Duration((float)1/DRAW_RATE).sleep();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nevermind, I just used X11 libraries and the drawing area widget to accomplish the same thing in a roundabout way. I think the GTK_GL_AREA widget is broken in 3.16/3.18. No one seems to be using it, anyway.

Comment: The problem is probably elsewhere in your code: if you provide a runnable example of the "Merely packing the gl_area is what causes the other UI elements to freeze" phenomenon (should be about 10 lines), someone might be able to point out a possible problem. GtkGLArea certainly works, see gtk3-demo for an example.